# How do I send the 'setMark' escape code in Windows Terminal or iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, windows-terminal, escape-sequences

[Windows Terminal now supports setMark](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-15-release/#scroll-marks-experimental) which originally came from [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html).

**How do I add a mark (non interactively, ie so I can use this in my $PS1)?** The docs have a screenshot of the relevant text rather than characters:

[image: setmark]

I'm relatively sure it is:

```
echo -e 'Mark this Line\x1b]1337;SetMark\x07'
```

I have `"experimental.showMarksOnScrollbar": true` enabled on my profile but it doesn't seem to work. I expected a graphical mark on the scroll bar to appear after running this command.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: We sorted this out over in https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15057.

> We never enabled that feature for Stable builds. It's still in Preview-only builds.

Make sure you're using Terminal **Preview**. Marks aren't enabled in Terminal (stable).

We're hoping to round them out for 1.19 (stable), but I'm not making any promises.